Creating instance of class for Keyed Dependency Injection in ASP.NET
I have a class DbCheck that implements the ICheck interface from a company NuGet package.
I use class DbCheck to Health Check database used in the project. But there're 3 databases in project, so I need to have all of them registered, like this.
var db1 = new DbCheck(checkName, dataConnection, tableInfo);
services.AddScoped<DbCheck>(provider => db1);

var db2 = new DbCheck(checkName, dataConnection, tableInfo);
services.AddScoped<DbCheck>(provider => db2);

var db3 = new DbCheck(checkName, dataConnection, tableInfo);
services.AddScoped<DbCheck>(provider => db3);

But when I do that, I get only db3 registered.
When I try to have different classes for every database, which inherit from DbCheck, and register each class separately, I get an error, probably which occurs in the NuGet method.
I tried other ways, that also didn't work.
I'd like to try something like this,
services.AddKeyedScoped<DbCheck>("db1", provider => db1);
services.AddKeyedScoped<DbCheck>("db2", provider => db2);
services.AddKeyedScoped<DbCheck>("db1", provider => db3);

But AddKeyedScoped method doesn't take this parameters, how to do something like that?
Thanks everyone, I think, the problem is in the nuget package from my company that I use, because no way works for this case

Why do you need this to be scoped when you are effectively creating a singleton here?

"But when I do that, I get only db3 registered." This is incorrect. If you look inside the ServiceCollection, you'll see all three registrations. If only one check gets  executed, that's because you (or the library  you are using) calls IServiceProvider.GetService rather than GetServices. I think you need to consult with the library owners rather than here on Stack Overflow.

It is because the AddKeyedScoped method has slightly different signature. Here's correct usage:
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ICheck, DbCheck>("key1", (sp, key) => db)

Example application:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ICheck, Check1>("key1", (sp, key) => new Check1());
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ICheck, Check2>("key2", (sp, key) => new Check2());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", ([FromKeyedServices("key1")]ICheck check1, [FromKeyedServices("key2")] ICheck check2) =>
{
    return new
    {
        Check1 = check1.Name,
        Check2 = check2.Name,
    };
})
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

public interface ICheck
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Check1 : ICheck
{
    public string Name => "Check1";
}

public class Check2 : ICheck
{
    public string Name => "Check2";
}

Reference:
ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddKeyedScoped Method
